# How much experience do you get for feeding dragons?

Tags: dragonvale

I've found many references to getting experience for feeding dragons, and I recall the in game tutorial mentioning it.  I've searched all over, and I can't find the exact formula for treats to experience.  What is the ratio or formula for treats to experience?

Comment: This I'd like to know. It's more for feeding higher level dragons, probably a % of the food used.

Comment: Huh, I thought maybe you'd know, given your other question.  I was all prepared to do some SCIENCE, then realized I was lacking this piece of the maths. *sad face*

Comment: I know that it gives XP but I have no way to measure the XP it gives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

Someone with more nefarious internet skills than myself devised a way to snoop traffic out of Dragonvale.  He apparently was trying to crack the tough of nut of "breeding magic", but in the process, he found [definitive evidence](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Dunkelzahn1/In-Depth_look_into_the_client-server_communication_of_DragonVale) that feeding your dragon gives you **20 xp per food**.  This means that treats are decisively the best investment of your money because:

- Buying food nets you experience at a 2 gold : 1 xp ratio
- Feeding treats nets you signifcant additional experience.  When looking at the Sarjin Pepper the overall transaction results in 500k gold : 450k xp.  This is 1.11 gold: 1 xp ratio - much better than other options.
- Feeding treats increases your dragons gold output, and levels shrines - a long term investiment in your park.

### Empirical evidence

I devised an imperfect way to measure how much experience you get for anything.  It is not exact, but for the purposes of other comparisons it may be sufficient.  The short answer is that this method suggests feeding your dragon gives ~15 xp per food.  This backs up the packet snooping tactics used at the link referenced above.

To determine this first I took a screen cap of my park.  For this shot I quick grew a large quantity of food to make the resolution better:
[image: Baseline]

Next I fed every last delicious morsel of that food to my hungry dragons:
[image: Fed Dragons]

Finally, I bought something I knew the xp value of.  In this case, 2x Shard of Tul - costing 200,000 coins and netting 100,000 xp.:
[image: Shards of Tul]

I then took these pictures, aligned them, and opened them in MS Paint.  Paint has an X,Y coordinate marker, which allowed me to compare the bar length between images.  I came up with a conversion factor of about 50,000 xp per tick in Paint (which will only apply for my level) based on the Shards of Tul.  Given that, I measured about 10 ticks by feeding dragons 32,800 food.

**10 * 50,000 = ~500,000 xp**

**32,800 * x = ~500,000 xp**

**32,800 * 15 = 493,200 xp**

Hence, using this method I estimate the xp value of feeding dragons to be 15 xp / food.  Given the innacuracies of this procedure, it seems to reasonably back up an actual xp / food ration of **20 xp / food** as referenced at the link in the top of this answer.

Comment: I don't think that can be right, I should be getting >9,000,000 for getting a dragon to level 15 if that's the case, which is a larger bump than I'm seeing when leveling dragons. I'll try and double check next time I have a dragon to level

Comment: If you can do before and after screen caps it would be helpful, especially if you can blow some money on decorations for a relative reference. You can screen cap by pressing home and lock buttons simultaneously, in case you were unaware.